# rails 3 protect_from_forgery not doing anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried to fake forgery request in my rails 3.0.8 app with no success

I have regular form and I changed the auth key with Tamper before submit it
at this point I would expect rails to reset the session and therefor signout the current_user
however it didn't happen, the action completed successfully and the user stay signed in

I have the protect_from_forgery statement in my application controller
and I tried to change config.consider_all_requests_local to false

Answer (score 6):

Indeed... it does something but you have to code it.

The previous behavior was removed, it's a controversial decision but you can get it back including the following code in your `ApplicationController`:

```
def handle_unverified_request
  #add here code to empty the session
  raise ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
end
```

Comment: the current behavior should be that handle_unverified_request? reset session, and it doesn't do that

Comment: In addition, I tried your code and it still doesn't change anything

Comment: just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090063/rails-3-protect-from-forgery-not-working-correctly  I don't know why your app isn't working

Comment: The problem was just a bug in the Firefox Tamper plugin. the session is reset now when expected too.

Comment: Ouch... Time wasted then. I understand I answered your question?